# How to get COUNT from two or more tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, group-by

I have three tables:

**cities**:
id|name

**companies**:
id|city_id

**users**:
id|city_id

How can I count how many times cities were touched **in companies and users tables at once** and group it by cities.name?
I only get how to do it from one table by this query:

```sql
SELECT cities.name AS city, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM users 
JOIN cities on users.city_id = cities.id 
GROUP BY cities.name;
```

But totally missed how to count it from two or even more tables... Need some help.

An example of a result should be like:

```
city           count  
Amsterdam      5
London         7
```

Comment: How does this result reflect the count **from companies and users** ?  This is unclear when no input data is given....

Comment: @Luuk this result is just an example. The point is in how to make such query

Comment: One should not add companies and users, for the same reason as not comparing [apples with pears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges) (or oranges)

Comment: Luuk's comment was kind of snarky, but I agree with the point. The simplest solution is to run two separate queries. One to count users per country, and a second query to count companies per country. There is no need to get both results in one query.

Comment: better to use the city_id, there could the two cities with the same name

Comment: Your example is insufficient to fully understand your question, please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the combination of `id` and `city_id` for both `users` and `companies` table are unique, then you may try this method:

```
SELECT ct.id, ct.name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT us.id) AS user_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT cm.id) AS company_count
  FROM cities ct
    LEFT JOIN users us 
     ON ct.id=us.city_id
  LEFT JOIN companies cm
     ON ct.id=cm.city_id
GROUP BY ct.id, ct.name
```

[Fiddle test](https://dbfiddle.uk/7qJVci1m)

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed. In this case, user_count and company_count must be as one column, not separated on two ones. And, accordingly, these two column must be summed. 
The main task: I have to know how many times each city was touched in two tables together. (in users and companies in our case)

Comment: I'm not sure what is the significance of having just one combined count column vs two separate count columns but you can just add both of the count result https://dbfiddle.uk/5DAgXH2V

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed! There is no actual significance, it was a question on an interview and I was interested how to do it, maybe one day i'll need it. Thank you anyway! I'll accept the answer